# Object is not a function (handsontable)

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm newbie javascript and I have some problem is : Object is not a function. This is my code

```
function getTable(options) {
    var exampleContainer1 = document.getElementById('example1');
    var ht = new Handsontable(exampleContainer1, options);
    return ht;
}
```

any people help me to resolve this problem, please :D

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8oynpdwt/1/

Comment: I believe the issue is that `Handsontable` isn't a function - maybe it is not defined before this code is being executed?

Comment: I agree with @logikal - do you have a script tag that imports the handsontable library?

Comment: yes, I have @sfletche

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't know why I cannot using that? I also added library for handsontable but it still not working :(

Comment: @user3040408 Make sure you're script is being executed after the script has loaded - execute your code once `document` fires the `ready` event.

Answer (score 1):

Please include the 3rd party js

```
<script src="dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="dist/handsontable.full.css">
```

And the div should be

```
<div id="example1" class="dataTable"></div>
```

Comment: it might be helpful to show a [cdn link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handsontable/0.14.1/handsontable.full.js) instead of a relative path

Comment: Please check your option content.